# python split and re.split not capturing what appear to be either tabs or spaces in string

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, split

I have a string like:

```
'Agendas / Schedules meetings and speakers       4 F     1928-1209       Box 2'
```

And I am trying to split it on what appear to be tabs. Though if I print with `print repr(str)` I only see special characters at the end:

```
'Agendas / Schedules meetings and speakers       4 F     1928-1209       Box 2\r\n'
```

And if I try things like `print re.split('\t+', str)` or `print re.split('\s+', str)`, nothing is split, ie output is still:

```
['Agendas / Schedules meetings and speakers       4 F     1928-1209       Box 2\r\n']
```

Is there a way to isolate these fixed width items if regex is not working out?

Update: am hoping to split exclusively on the larger white spaces, so .split() creating a list element of every word is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: if this is fixed. why not copy&paste it into the regex?

Comment: You say python `split` doesn't work but you don't show the results of that.  What happens if you do `str.split()`?  Oh, and you should avoid calling your variable `str`, because it shadows the python builtin.

Comment: Could you post the output of `' '.join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in str)` please? Also you should note that str is a bad variable name as it masks the built-in <type 'str'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the input. Didn't realize that python had a zero-width-space bug (http://bugs.python.org/issue13391)

Anyway, it appears that matching on more than one whitespace did the trick:

```
>>>re.split('\s{2,}', s)
['Agendas / Schedules meetings and speakers', '4 F', '1928-1209', 'Box 2']
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've ran across this a few times in the past, you may have a case of *Zero-Width-Space*.

```
>>> s = 'Agendas / Schedules meetings and speakers       4 F     1928-1209       Box 2'
>>> re.split(ur'[\u200b\s]+', s, flags=re.UNICODE)

['Agendas', '/', 'Schedules', 'meetings', 'and', 'speakers', '4', 'F', '1928-1209', 'Box', '2']
```

Comment: Wouldn't the unicode characters show up when the `repr` is printed?

Answer (score 1):

The split() method of string will split on whitespace by default.  So:

```
print str.split()
```

should do the trick.